# Interrupt exception in kafka library

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-msk, amazon-msk

I am getting a kafka exception in java library

thread_name
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:155)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1762)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1285)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeThrowInterruptException(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:520)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:281)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1499)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1236)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

At this time when this issue is happening, we are getting **SumOffsetLag** high values in cloudwatch

Comment: You need to find the root cause of the interrupt - some other thread in your application interrupted the consumer thread. There is nothing in the framework that would do that.